# JOINing 3 tables, SUM() values from 2 of the tables (MYSQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm confused on how to get the # of purchases **AND** the vote count for each item.

Doing two simple JOINs to connect the following 3 tables multiplies the `purchase_count` by the number of entries in the `Votes` table:

```
SELECT item_id, item_name, sum(backing_status) purchase_count, sum(vote) vote_count 
FROM Items
LEFT JOIN Purchases ON Items.item_id=Purchases.item_id
LEFT JOIN Votes ON Items.item_id=Votes.item_id
where purchase_status='bought' 
group by Items.item_id 

Table Items
item_id item_name
1           item_1
2           item_2
3           item_3

Table Purchases
item_id purchase_status 
1           bought          
2           bought          
1           bought          

Table Votes
item_id    vote 
1           1         
2           1          
3           -1         
1           -1
1           -1
```

the desired output is:

```
item_id item_name  purchase_count vote_count
1           item_1      2          -1 //sum of -2 downvotes + 1 upvote
2           item_2      1           1
3           item_3      0          -1
```

I probably need to subquery but can't quite figure out the query. Or is there a better way?

Comment: You'll probably want to just make 2 queries.

Comment: @Kevin thanks, you say this because of performance reasons or more for ease of code/DB maintenance?

Comment: @timpeterson both. The way to do this in one query will require using 2 `subqueries`. Subqueries are know to be slower, plus using them usually makes your sql code hard to read. IMO it will be easier to just do a `SELECT SUM(vote) FROM votes` and `SELECT COUNT(item_id) FROM purchases`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the following code which uses subqueries with both aggregates to get the result:

```
select i.item_id,
  i.item_name,
  coalesce(p.TotalBought, 0)TotalBought,
  coalesce(v.vote_count, 0) vote_count
from items i
left join
(
  select item_id, count(*) TotalBought
  from purchases
  where purchase_status = 'bought'
  group by item_id
) p
  on i.item_id = p.item_id
left join
(
  select item_id, sum(vote) vote_count
  from votes
  group by item_id
) v
  on i.item_id = v.item_id;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/33085/8).

You could also write this without two subqueries but you will need to place the WHERE filter of `purchase_status` on the JOIN:

```
select i.item_id,
  i.item_name,
  count(p.item_id) TotalBought,
  coalesce(v.vote_count, 0) vote_count
from items i
left join purchases p
  on i.item_id = p.item_id
left join
(
  select item_id, sum(vote) vote_count
  from votes
  group by item_id
) v
  on i.item_id = v.item_id
group by i.item_id, i.item_name;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/33085/12)

Comment: -@bluefeet, awesome, thanks, i've never used `coalesce()` I need to learn about that

Comment: @timpeterson `coalesce` replaces `null` with a 0 or whatever value you want to replace it with.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT item_id, item_name, sum(backing_status) AS purchase_count, SUM(vote) 
    AS vote_count
FROM Items i
LEFT JOIN Purchases p on i.item_id = p.item_id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT SUM(vote), item_id FROM votes GROUP BY item_id) AS grv 
    on grv.item_id = i.item_id
WHERE purchase_status='bought';
```